# How can an uncalled test affect another in Go?

Tags: testing, go

I have a test function `TestJobqueue()` in https://github.com/VertebrateResequencing/wr/blob/develop/jobqueue/jobqueue_test.go that I can call in isolation: `go test -tags netgo ./jobqueue -v -run 'TestJobqueue$'`.

I recently started getting test failures related to boltdb (one of my dependencies) bombing out with `signal SIGBUS: bus error code` panics, or just normally failing tests because the database couldn't be opened. But only when working off an NFS mounted directory. Fair enough, I or boltdb have some kind of NFS-related bug.

But the thing I can't wrap my head around is that I only get these errors when an entirely different test function exists.

As per the comments in `TestREST()` in https://github.com/VertebrateResequencing/wr/blob/92fb61ccd7819c8f1edfa8cce8468c4250d40ea7/jobqueue/rest_test.go, if I call `Serve(serverConfig)` (a function in the package being tested, a function call which is made many times in `TestJobqueue()` and other test functions) in that test function, `TestJobqueue()` fails. If I don't, it doesn't.

In short, the failure of tests in one test function can be controlled by the value of a boolean in a test function that I'm not running.

How is this possible?

Edit: to address some points brought up by the first answer, `TestJobqueue()` is being run in isolation. No other test runs before or after it. If the database file already exists, `Serve()` results in those files being deleted first, then a new one created to run the new set of tests. The odd thing that I'm seeking an answer for is how an unexecuted function can have this side effect. I can demonstrate it is really unexecuted by beginning or ending `TestREST()` with a `panic` call: the output of that panic is never seen, but `TestJobqueue()` failure can still be controlled by the boolean in `TestREST()` (if the panic comes at the end).

Edit2: this turns out to be caused by an unusual thing I do in `TestJobqueue()`, which is to call `go test` on itself. Needless to say, if you do this, strange things can happen...

Comment: See edit below in response to your edits - I suspect you're running the other test by mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*In short, the failure of tests in one test function can be controlled by the value of a boolean in a test function that I'm not running.*

This is not a great summary. Your test starts a server. The other test starts a server, clearly, the problem is there. You appear to have commented out the bit of code that stops the server at the end of the test? You can't run two servers on the same port.

You probably have a port conflict or some network condition that is triggered by running the two servers at once, because they both appear to use a similar (identical?) config loaded like this:

```
config := internal.ConfigLoad("development", true)
```

Running with no config uses default values, avoiding the conflict, running with config causes the conflict. So to pin it down, try creating a config with one setting at a time till you find the config setting that causes the problem (most likely Port or WebPort). Alternatively, make sure the tests stop the server at the end.

[EDIT] Looks like you have narrowed it down to DBFile config setting by changing one at a time. This implies the server starts a new db instance - if both try to use the same file for a new db, this would cause contention and the second test to run would fail.

It's not entirely clear from your description above what you're doing or what the problem is, so you could try to improve that to state exactly the sequence of actions and the problem. If for example you have previously run a test which creates a db, it could affect later test runs because of the presence of a db file, so your tests are not completely independent.

[EDIT 2 - after further edits to question] 
If commenting out TestREST completely solves your problem (or a panic before it starts), and given changing it breaks the other test, you are executing TestREST somehow.

Looking at your code for jobqueue_test, it appears to invoke go test so you might be running more tests that you assume? Given you don't see the panic output I'd suspect your use of exec.Command in this big test. Try removing bits of the failing test till it works to narrow down exactly which invocation is running the other test. Calling go test within a test is pretty unusual!

https://github.com/VertebrateResequencing/wr/blob/develop/jobqueue/jobqueue_test.go#L2445

Comment: The point is, or what I don't understand, is that the other test isn't starting a server, because the other test isn't being executed.

Comment: Stopping the server at the end makes no difference; the problem is seen with the real commented-out code in TestREST(). And I can't change Port or WebPort, since the real test code in TestREST() needs to use the same parameters as all the other tests that start the server in all the other test functions. The full test suite is supposed to run each jobqueue package test function sequentially. And it does, looking at the console output. But somehow TestREST() interferers with a test function that runs before it.

Comment: Changing the path to the DBFile to a value that is unique to TestREST() avoids the crashes. But again, I would like to understand how this can be the case, that a test function I'm not executing is calling my Serve() function. I can put a panic before the Serve() line in TestREST() and it doesn't result in that panic.

Comment: Something in your assumptions here is wrong. If possible I'd comment out all other tests, and try running these two tests together if you think they are conflicting. There is an obvious cause for a problem here though - TestREST runs a server, which could cause all kinds of interactions (for example opening db, using a port, etc). Try to isolate the problem and you'll find it. It looks like you are making progress - if DBFile is the culprit, there might be contention over that file (not a port).

Comment: I addressed your edited questions in an edit to the OP.

Comment: Thanks, I completely forgot about my self-calling of go test. I didn't put my "don't call this test under that circumstance" code in TestRest().